# Pass a NULL in a parameter to a DateTime field in a stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, parameters, null

I have a stored procedure which updates a database using the parameters I supply but I'm having trouble passing a NULL to the stored procedure

The field I need to make NULL is a DateTime field

```
DB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", NULL)
```

This gives me the error

> 'NULL' is not declared. 'Null' constant is no longer supported; use 'System.DBNull' instead

So I tried

```
DB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DBNull.Value.ToString())
```

But this produces the value `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000` in the column as it's passing a `""` to the field

I also tried

```
DB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DBNull.Value)
```

But it produces this error

> Value of type 'System.DBNull' cannot be converted to 'String'.

Has anybody got any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you ommit the parameter completly?

Comment: @Mick, that outta do it, too. I'd like to see what params his sp is expecting

Comment: Use the `.AddWithValue` call with care - how would .NET know in this case what **type** your param should be, if you pass in `DBNull.Value` ?? See LukeH's answer - **be specific** and you'll save yourself a lot of grief! (and really hard-to-find bugs, too!)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try something like this, using [`Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbys3e9s.aspx) rather than `AddWithValue`:

```
DB.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DBNull.Value;
```

Comment: +1 exactly - how should ADO.NET figure out what **type** your param is going to be if you pass in `DBNull.Value` ?? Be clear and specific!

Answer (score 27):

Or you can add your parameter like this, which gives it a null value in the database if your variable is null:

```
DB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", myDateTime ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
```

you need to set it as a nullable type as Amit mentioned.

More details and background available at http://evonet.com.au/overview-of-c-nullable-types/

Answer (score 3):

Try this

If you are using class and its property and those property values are used as parameter then you can do this

chnage the signature of the property to

```
public DateTime? myDateTime = null;// Here ? is used to make the property nullable.
```

Also if your date column is of type varchar then correct it to Date (Sql2008) / DateTime(2005).

//change parameter to this

```
@SomeDate datetime = null (as suggested by chris)
```

**Allow the field to accept null and then pass the value as**

```
DB.Parameters.Add("@date", DBNull.Value)
```

Comment: Won't change anything - the problem is that with the `AddWithValue` and `DBNull.Value`, the ADO.NET runtime doesn't know what type you want it to be .....

Answer (score 1):

This is an example. It's work for me

```
if(obj.myDate == DateTime.MinValue)
{
    aCommand.Parameters.Add("dateParameter", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DBNull.Value;
}
else
{
    aCommand.Parameters.Add("dateParameter", SqlDbType.Date).Value = obj.myDate ;
}
```