# ms access 2010 and vs2010 how to connect

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ms-access

Program crash in `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` row

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Private Sub RefreshData()
        If Not conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            'open connection
            conn.Open()
        End If

        Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Oznaka as [Oznaka], " & _
                                             "ReN as [ReN], RmN " & _
                                             " FROM Tabela ORDER BY Oznaka", conn)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        'fill data to datatable
        da.Fill(dt)

        'offer data in data table into datagridview
        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

        'close connection
        conn.Close()
    End Sub


    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        If Not conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            'open connection if it is not yet open
            conn.Open()
        End If

        cmd.Connection = conn
        'check whether add new or update
        If Me.txtOznaka.Tag & "" = "" Then
            'add new
            'add data to table
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Tabela(Oznaka, ReN, RmN) " & _
                                " VALUES('" & Me.txtOznaka.Text & "','" & Me.txtReN.Text & "','" & _
                                Me.txtRmN.Text & "'')"

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Else
            'update data in table
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Tabela " & _
                        " SET Oznaka=" & Me.txtOznaka.Text & _
                        ", ReN='" & Me.txtReN.Text & "'" & _
                        ", RmN='" & Me.txtRmN.Text & "'" & _
                                   " WHERE Oznaka=" & Me.txtOznaka.Tag
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        End If
        'refresh data in list
        RefreshData()
        'clear form
        'Me.btnClear.PerformClick()

        'close connection
        conn.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        conn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0; Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\baza.mdb"
        '
        'get data into list
        Me.RefreshData()
    End Sub



End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the `INSERT` or the `UPDATE` query when it crashes?

If it's the  `INSERT` query, it's probably because the SQL string has one `'` too much at the end:

```
... Me.txtRmN.Text & "'')"

                       ^
                       here!
```

If it's the `UPDATE` query: if `Oznaka` is a string column, put the value in quotes:

```
" SET Oznaka='" & Me.txtOznaka.Text & "'" & _
```

instead of

```
" SET Oznaka=" & Me.txtOznaka.Text & _
```

**An even better solution for both of these issues would be: use SQL parameters in your queries instead of concatenating strings.**

Here are some examples to get started:

- [INSERT with transaction and parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386588/insert-with-transaction-and-parameters)
- [Pass a NULL in a parameter to a DateTime field in a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182032/pass-a-null-in-a-parameter-to-a-datetime-field-in-a-stored-procedure)